# How can I view or search across all the group direct messages sent by Bob to groups where Alice is present in Slack?

Tags: search, slack

I use https://slack.com/. I have group messages between the following groups (I am also a member of each of these groups):

1. Alice, Bob
2. Alice, Bob, Charlie
3. Bob, Charlie
4. Alice, Bob, Charlie, David
5. Bob, Charlie, David
6. Alice, Bob, Charlie, David, Elena

How can I view or search across all the group direct messages sent by Bob to groups where Alice is present in Slack? (in this example, that's groups 1, 2, 4, and 6).

If I search:

```
from:@Bob
```

it lists/searches across all the direct messages and group direct messages sent by Bob. But I don't want to see the  messages that Bob sent in groups where Alice is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `from:@Bob with:@Alice`?